# Why does using fetch data in nuxt3

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm new to Nuxt. I have an error retrieving data. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What is the translation of this? Please put a bit more effort here.

Comment: Please post the code and error as text, not an images.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `useFetch` without specifying the type of the result, typescript cannot know, what type it is.

You could tell typescript that you are receiving a list of users from an endpoint and what a user looks like by doing something like this:

```js
interface User {
  id: number
  name: string
  email: string
}

const {data: users} = useFetch<User[]>('api.example.com');
```

`useFetch` returns the (parsed) body of the response in `data`. Looking at what the URL `https://reqres.in/api/users` really provides, you would probably want to access the `data` attribute of the body. You'd need something like this to get to the list of users:

```js
interface User {
  id: number
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
}

const { data: body } = useFetch<{ data: User[] }>('https://reqres.in/api/users')
const users = body.value?.data ?? []
```